# When change of variable makes an empty interval

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Please consider the following case:

$$I = \int^1_{-1}x^2dx$$
$$u(x) = x^2 \rightarrow du = 2x\,dx$$
$$u(-1) = 1, u(1) = 1$$

So

$$I = \int^1_1\frac{u}{2\sqrt u} du = 0$$

Obviously the problem here is to only consider the positive root of u. I don't know how to consider both roots. This example is trivial but I have another example where such substitution would be really helpful:

$$I = \int^1_{-1}\frac{x^2(1 - x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{3} - \frac{x^2(1 - x^2)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} - \frac{x^4(1 - x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{3} dx$$

I don't want you to solve it for me using another method, I know how to use an integral solver online. My question is how to properly do the change of variable.

Comment: The derivative of $x^2$ isn't 2

Comment: related: [$u$-substitution always evaluates to $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325203/u-substitution-always-evaluates-to-0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While it's certainly true that $du = 2x\,dx$ over the whole region of integration, it's not true that $x = \sqrt{u}$ over the region. This is only true for $x > 0$, so you can't apply it to the whole integral. Instead, you need to split it apart and use the correct transformation $x = -\sqrt{u}$ for the region $x < 0$.

In general, if your change of variables $u(x)$ has a multivalued inverse, you'll need to split the integral into the regions where each possible inverse function $x(u)$ applies.

Answer (score 13):

In general you need to use a one-to-one change of variable; thus for instance if you were to compute $\int_{-1}^1 x^2 dx$ you would split into $\int_{-1}^0 x^2 dx + \int_0^1 x^2 dx$. Then each of those integrals, after substitution and simplification, becomes $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} u^{1/2} du$.

(That said, there are some situations where by basically breaking the rules twice you cancel out your mistakes and get the right answer; see [Why can the trig sub $x=\cosh(\theta)$ be used to solve the integral: $\int \frac{1}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006337/why-can-the-trig-sub-x-cosh-theta-be-used-to-solve-the-integral-int-fra/3006350#3006350) for instance.)

Comment: It is not necessary for changes of variable to be one-to-one, see my comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1101421/5316

Comment: @MatthewTowers Yes, it is true that $\int_a^b f'(x) dx$ is always $f(b) - f(a)$, regardless of injectivity, which means you can do various similar things *also* regardless of injectivity. What injectivity buys you is a lack of a singularity in $\frac{dx}{du}$, which is a serious problem for, say, $u=x^2$ on $[a,b]$ with $a<0,b>0$.