# Integrate without using the property that the function is odd

Tags: integration, statistics, definite-integrals, beta-function, even-and-odd-functions

Integrate using substitution(not trigonometric) the following. I will share how I did it, even though the answer is not right.

$$\int_{-1}^1 x \sqrt{1-x^2} dx $$
$$  Substituting \space x^2=y $$
$$2xdx=dy \space $$
$$ \space limit:\space  0 \space to \space 1$$
$$ Therefore \space the \space integral \space changes \space to$$
$$ \frac12\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-y} du$$
$$= -\frac13 [(1-u)^{\frac32}]_0^1$$
$$=\frac13$$

After integration  if $$ y=x^2$$
is  substituted, correct  answer  0  is  obtained.   But  shouldn't  this give  same  answer  even  if  it's  not  re-substituted,  given  the  limits are  changed? Can  someone  correct  the  mistake?

Comment: If $y=x^2$, then $x=\pm1 \implies y=1$, hence $\displaystyle \int_1^1\cdots dy=$ ...

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032622/when-change-of-variable-makes-an-empty-interval/3032655#3032655).

Comment: Try this substitution: $u=1-x^2$, then check limits of integration.